# Is there a term to describe what movie/game/anime/etc. a music piece is famous for?

Tags: terminology

For example, "My Heart Will Go On" is from the movie "Titanic", "Still Alive" is from the game "Portal" and "Gotta Catch Em All" is from the anime "Pokémon". Obviously there are still artists/composers behind the songs, so listing "Titanic" as 'artist' feels wrong.

Is there a common term that can be used to describe what these songs are famous for, that can be used in a simple format like `XXX: Titanic` and works not only for movies, but also for games, animes, etc.?

Comment: A "hit single" or "featured track" from/of a Soundtrack?

Answer (score 3):

I think the general term people tend to resort to is ***featured in***.

For example:

> *My Heart Will Go On* as performed by Celine Dion
>
> ***Featured in:***  Titanic